# Expected value of $e^X$ where X is geometrically distributed

Tags: probability

Random variable $X$ is geometrically distributed with parameter $2/3$, that is $\mathbb{P}(X=k)=2/3^k$, $k=1,2,...$ I have to find $\mathbb{E}e^X$.

So let $Y=e^X$. Then $$\mathbb{P}(Y=k)=\mathbb{P}(X=\ln{k})=2/3^{\ln{k}}$$
And $$\mathbb{E}Y=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{2k}{3^{\ln{k}}}$$

I have a strong feeling I'm doing this wrong... Do you know how to do it correctly?

Comment: We can use the [moment-generating function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function) to find $\operatorname Ee^X$. The moment-generating function is given by $M_X(t)=\operatorname Ee^{tX}$ for $t\in\mathbb R$. We can find the moment-generating function of the [geometric distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) and evaluate it at $t=1$.

Comment: Chinny84: It work for continuous variable only. Here, $Y$ is discrete.

Comment: cheers @idm :).

Comment: $\mathbb{P}(X = \ln k) = 0$, since $\ln k \notin \mathbb{Z}_+$ while $X$ attains (with non-zero probability) only positive integer values.

Comment: Ooook, so what does that mean? $Y$ is, umm, never going to happen so to say? It's expected value is 0?

Comment: I erased my post, I was wrong (I forgot the $e^k$) Anyway, you've got many correct answer below. Sorry :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to use this formula:

$$ \mathbb{E}[g(X)] = \int_{\Omega}g(X)\text{d}\mathbb{P} $$

If $X$ is discrete and attains with non-zero probability only positive integer values it can be rewritten as follows:

$$ \mathbb{E}[g(X)] = \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} g(k)\mathbb{P}(X = k)$$

So the final answer is $$\mathbb{E}[Y] = \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}\frac{2e^k}{3^k} = 2\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}(\frac{e}{3})^k = 2\frac{\frac{e}{3}}{1 - \frac{e}{3}} = \frac{2e}{3 - e}$$

Comment: Oh, so that's how it's done! Thank you for thorough explanation!

Answer (score 2):

$$\mathbb{E}Y = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}e^kP(X=k)=2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(\frac{e}{3})^k = 2\left(\frac{1}{1-\frac{e}{3}}-1\right)$$
The first equality is one of the elementary properties of expectation.

Answer (score 1):

Here are my 2 cents:

The probability $P[X=k] = 2 (\frac {1}{3})^k$ and indeed $P[Y=k] = P[X=ln(k)] = 2 (\frac {1}{3})^{ln(k)}$

But! You say that the expectation is $\sum_k P[Y=k]k$, which can't be, because among other things, $P[Y=k]=0$ because $Y$ cannot receive an integer value.

The correct formula is:
$E[Y]=E[f(X)]=\sum_{k=1}^\infty f(k)P[X=k]=\sum_{k=1}^\infty e^k2 (\frac {1}{3})^k = 2 \sum_{k=1}^\infty (\frac {e}{3})^k = \frac{-2e}{e-3}$

Answer (score 1):

That's not quite right, let me explain. Since $X$ takes the values $1,2,...$, we know that $Y=e^X$ will take the values $e^1,e^2,...$.

When finding the expectation, you need to sum over all values the variable takes. That's why when finding $\mathbb{E} X$, we sum over $k=1,2,3,...$, i.e. $$\mathbb{E} X = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k \mathbb{P}(X=k)$$

In the same way, when calculating $\mathbb{E}Y$, you should sum over $k=e^1,e^2,e^3,...$ or, equivalently, $$\mathbb{E} Y = \sum_{s=1}^{\infty} e^s \mathbb{P}(Y=e^s) = \sum_{s=1}^{\infty} e^s \mathbb{P}(X=s) = \sum_{s=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{2e^s}{3^s}$$